# Trying to execute python command through php but permission errors

Tags: php, python

I uploaded an image file and copied it from temporary folder to a folder inside /var/www/. Then, tried to execute a python command via php where the *exec()* command is in the following format.

```
exec('python file.py $_FILES["file"]["name"]');
```

and even doing the following does not work,

```
exec('python file.py' + $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
```

In the python side, I am trying to read the filename and do some processing on it and save the image.

```
source = cv2.imread(sys.argv[1])
#some processing    
cv2.imwrite("upload/result.png", resultimage)
```

*Note:* The uploaded images are being shown as owned by www-data group after upload. I have added my user to the www-data group and have done the following as well.

```
sudo chown -R tilaprimera:www-data upload

sudo chmod -R g+s upload
```

where here upload is my folder storing the uploaded images. I have made the python script executable too,

```
sudo chmod +x script.py
```

and also the script.py is perfectly running okay as

```
./script.py
```

Why is the python script not executing via the php?

Answer (score 1):

In the python script file, the directory change was done as

```
os.chdir('/var/www/upload')
```

and in the php side, I gave the full path for the python script to run

```
exec('python /var/www/upload/script.py ' . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
```

This way, the problem got solved.